# How to append an associative into another associative array by continuing the increment of keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following associative array:

```php
0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '0000' (length=4)
      'polling_id' => string '0' (length=1)
1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '0001' (length=4)
      'polling_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

And I have this second associative array:

```php
0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '0002' (length=4)
      'polling_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'backup_id' => string '4500' (length=4)
1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '0003' (length=4)
      'polling_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'backup_id' => string '4500' (length=4)
```

I want it to look like:

```php
0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '0000' (length=4)
      'polling_id' => string '0' (length=1)
1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '0001' (length=4)
      'polling_id' => string '1' (length=1)
2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '0002' (length=4)
      'polling_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'backup_id' => string '4500' (length=4)
3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '0003' (length=4)
      'polling_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'backup_id' => string '4500' (length=4)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `array_merge($a1,$a2)`to merge these two arrays.